# Update a record field in a controller extension

Tags: apex, visualforce

• I currently have a custom object - Assessments__c

• A PDF is successfully created and attached to this object based on a custom button action on the page, using Apex and VisualForce

• I need to know how to update my Apex Code so when a PDF is created, it also checks a checkbox

Here is my current code

```
public class attachPDFToApplication {
    public Id recId {get;set;}
    Public List<Attachment> existingAttLst {get;set;}
    Public Assessment__c record {get;set;}
    Public Assessment__c assessment {get;set;}
    
    //constructor
    public attachPDFToApplication(ApexPages.StandardController standardPageController) {        
        recId = standardPageController.getId();
        record = (Assessment__c)standardPageController.getRecord();
        Datetime apllicationdate = datetime.now();   //field that will create the pdf
        String attName = 'SystemRec - '+ datetime.now() + '.pdf';
        existingAttLst  = new List<Attachment> ([Select id from Attachment where ParentId =: record.Id and Name =: attName limit 1]);
    }
   
    //method called from the Visualforce's action attribute
    public void attachPDF() {
        if(record.First_System_Rec_Created__c = false){
            record.First_System_Rec_Created__c = true;
            update record;
        }

       
        if(existingAttLst == null || existingAttLst.size() <1){
            Blob pdfBlob;
            PageReference pdfPage = Page.SystemRec2;
           
            pdfPage.getParameters().put('id',recId);
            pdfPage.setRedirect(true);
            try{
                pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContentAsPdf();
            }catch(exception e){
                pdfBlob = blob.valueOf('this is from excetion  '+e.getMessage());
                system.debug(e.getMessage());
            }
            system.debug('id==>'+recId );
            Attachment attach = new Attachment(ParentId = recId, Name = 'SystemRec - '+ datetime.now() + '.pdf', body = pdfBlob);
            insert attach;
        } else {
            system.debug('PDF already attached');
        }
    }
}
```

• You see, I'm trying to update the Boolean, record.First_System_Rec_Created__c, to 'True' at the same time the PDF is created

• If I remove the 'If' check from:

```
if(record.First_System_Rec_Created__c = false){
  record.First_System_Rec_Created__c = true;
  update record;
}
```

To make it simply:

```
record.First_System_Rec_Created__c = true;
update record;
```

when the function runs, the record updates the First_System_Rec_Created__c checkbox to 'true' as intended.

• However, when I attempt to only update it in the event the value is false, nothing happens.  I believe this might be because I'm not querying this field? But I'm not sure how to update my code further.

***What I've Tried:***

• I've tried to add a Query line for the field I'm trying to update by adding this to the Constructor:

```
standardPageController.addFields(new List<Boolean>{record.First_System_Rec_Created__c});
```

I get this error:

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void addFields(List<Boolean>) from the type ApexPages.StandardController
```

• Again, I was able to get around addfields, and no longer needed the above constructor, by adding this to my VF page:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Assessment__c.First_System_Rec_Created__c}" rendered="false"/>
```

• I've also tried adding this to the Constructor:

```
        Assessment__c assessment = [SELECT First_System_Rec_Created__c FROM Assessment__c WHERE Id = :recId LIMIT 1];
```

and then updating the if statement to this:

```
if(assessment.First_System_Rec_Created__c = false){
            record.First_System_Rec_Created__c = true;
            update record;
        }
```

• In this instance, the Apex code saves without error - However, when I attempt to run it by selecting the button on the object's page, I am met with this error:

```
Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!attachPDF}' in component <apex:page> in page systemrec2wrapper: Class.attachPDFToApplication.attachPDF: line 19, column 1
```

• This tells me that 'assessment' is null, which makes me think the Query isn't selecting anything?

I'm not sure how to correctly query the field I need and would love some help updating my actual code.

Comment: @identigral - Unfortunately, I don't believe so.  When I enter the suggested line, I am met with this error I'm having trouble resolve - "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void addFields(List<String>) from the type Assessment__c"

Comment: One issue i can see is in the apex constructor, you have defined "reccreated" boolenan variable again which is only available in the constructor scope. you should remove boolean keyword in the constructor for reccreated variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per getRecord() method documentation:

> Note that only the fields that are referenced in the associated Visualforce markup are available for querying on this SObject. All other fields, including fields from any related objects, must be queried using a SOQL expression.

So if First_System_Rec_Created__c field is not being used in VF page then you need to query that first before using it.

Also, you have again define "reccreated" variable in the constructor scope which will be of no use if you want updated value of "reccreated" variable in your "attachPDF" method.

**UPDATED SNIPPET**

```
    public Assessment__c assessment {get;set;}
    
    //constructor
    public attachPDFToApplication(ApexPages.StandardController standardPageController) {        
        recId = standardPageController.getId();
        record = (Assessment__c)standardPageController.getRecord();
        Datetime apllicationdate = datetime.now();   //field that will create the pdf
        String attName = 'SystemRec - '+ datetime.now() + '.pdf';
        existingAttLst  = new List<Attachment> ([Select id from Attachment where ParentId =: record.Id and Name =: attName limit 1]);
        //class member variable to be set here instead of defining a new method scope variable
        assessment = [SELECT First_System_Rec_Created__c FROM Assessment__c WHERE Id = :recId LIMIT 1];
    }
   
    //method called from the Visualforce's action attribute
    public void attachPDF() {
        if(assessment.First_System_Rec_Created__c = false){
            assessment.First_System_Rec_Created__c = true;
            update assessment ;
        }
```

Comment: I think I'm getting stuck on how to Query the field I need - Can you help me with how I need to update my code? I've updated my question with what I've tried.

Comment: You can simply perform an SOQL operation in constructor to fetch the value of the boolean field and then use it anywhere. Assessment__c assessment = [SELECT First_System_Rec_Created__c FROM Assessment__c WHERE Id = :recId LIMIT 1];

Comment: I added the above line to my Apex code and updated my if statement (please see above in the "What I've Tried" section for the update.  However, I'm getting a "Attempt to de-reference a null object" error when I start the process through pressing the button on the object.  Maybe the query isn't actually grabbing anything? Is there something I'm still missing here?

Comment: Here the problem is you are defining variables at class level (class scope) as well as in constructor (method level scope) and that is why assessment variable in constructor and in attachPDF method are two different variables.  Updated code snippet in the answer to fix null pointer issue.

Comment: I can confirm with the code snippet above (thank you) I no longer get any errors - However, when I go into a record and select the action to create the PDF, the checkbox remains 'false'

Comment: After further review - The Apex did not actually need an 'IF' statement - When the checkbox was already marked as 'True', the workflow running the capture on the Date/Time field did not run again. This worked as intended, although, the issue of not being able to actually grab the value of the field to run an IF statement on still persists. - I just no longer need the support for this specific instance.